# ObjC protocols potentially useless

Tags: objective-c, protocols, type-safety

In ObjC we can use protocols to restrict an `id` behavior, so we can declare something like 
`-(void)aMethod:(id<aProtocol>)aVar` which works very well until we provide a value or a non-`id` variable as `aVar`, but this gets completely broken since we can pass a generic `id` variable delcared without protocols specifiers... Is this normal? Is there any workaround? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to provide an `id` variable to your method that does not have the protocol?

Comment: Yes, and I can do that, that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (FINALLY) found out that using Objective-C++ is the way to go. Let's suppose I want to be able to pass `NSString` or `NSNumber` (instead of a too much generic `id` and instead of using protocols which become useless passing `id` values): well, I can create a C++ class having two distinct constructors, one for each ObjC class, so passing `id` values cannot be done anymore (almost directly). For example, let's take a look at

```
class NSStringOrNSNumber{
    public:
        NSStringOrNSNumber(NSString *);
        NSStringOrNSNumber(NSNumber *);
};
```

The great advantage is that methods/functions taking a `NSStringOrNSNumber` parameter can get NSString/NSNumber values DIRECTLY, since the constructor acts as an implicit cast. In other words, if we have

```
void aFunction(NSStringOrNSNumber param);
```

the following calls are perfectly valid:

```
aFunction(@"Hello!");
aFunction(@25);
```

The only (little) downside is that we need the class to implement a function if we want to get back the value passed to the constructor.

Using a C++ class constructor to get something like `id<NSCoding>` is still better the using `id<NSCoding>` directly: in fact, if we do the following

```
@class classOne, classTwo;

class NSCodingClass{
    private:
        NSCodingClass(classOne *);
        NSCodingClass(classTwo *);
    public:
        NSCodingClass(id<NSCoding>);
}
```

we won't be able to pass a generic `id` as a parameter (since it would be ambiguous: the compiler cannot know which constructor to call among the two private ones)

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the understanding that types in Objective-C are determined at runtime, not compile time. Just because you say that an object will be of type `id<aProtocol>` does not mean that at runtime it is guaranteed to be so.

The idea of specifying something as `id<aProtocol>` is to aid you as a developer and people using your code. It aids you as a developer because the compiler will warn (or error under ARC) if you attempt to call a method on something that the compiler can determine it doesn't think exists on instances of its supposed type (excluding forwarding which could mean an instance responds to something the compiler cannot determine). It aids people using your code as it tells them the contract that they should adhere to when interfacing with your code.

So, in your question you say that:

> but this gets completely broken if we pass a generic id variable delcared without protocols specifiers

Well, the compiler would warn and tell you that you're trying to pass something that does not conform to that protocol, except for the case of passing `id`. That's why you generally should try to type things more precisely than just `id`.

If you have a method defined like so:

```
- (void)aMethod:(id<aProtocol>)aVar
```

Then `aVar` could be of type `SomeSubclass` where that is defined like so:

```
@interface SomeSubclass : NSObject <aProtocol>
```

And you could then use `aMethod` like this:

```
SomeSubclass *obj = [SomeSubclass new];
[other aMethod:obj];
```

Comment: I know, but I always try to get the most at compile time

Comment: Sure. Then use protocols. I don't really see what you're trying to say?

Comment: I should not be able to pass generic id variables as id<aProtocol> ones... but the compiler doesn't complain if I do that

Comment: "Well, the compiler would warn" Actually, assigning something of type `id` to any other object pointer type (including `id<aProtocol>`) will never generate a warning because the point of `id` is that it turns off static type warnings.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `id` less, and declare variables and parameters using the correct types, where possible. That is to say: don't pass `id`s around. If you are implementing a collections class (for example), then `id`'s often useful.

My approach is to specify types, and introduce that type as local as possible in the source. So I omit `id` and add the type, and when (for instance) I take a reference from a collection, I create a variable:

```
MONType<MONProtocol>* thing = [array objectAtIndex:idx];
// now thing is correctly typed. use thing.
```

Similarly, if I have an `id` parameter, I declare a new variable:

```
- (IBAction)someAction:(id)sender
{
  NSButton * button = sender;
  // now use button, not sender
```

Protocols are *extremely* useful. Very often, better/cleaner than subclassing.

Comment: I'd like to: the problem occures when I can't do nothing more than pass values from a NSArray (for example) whose values are just id

Comment: @user732274 see my first code example. i declare a new variable.

Comment: Good example, but that's just a trick: what if I developed a framework for other developers and they pass an array of objects not adopting that protocol? I do know they must read the documentation first, I'm just wondering if there's any more reliable mechanism

Comment: @user732274 don't bother accommodating those clients. reverse the roles: if you wrote `[[NSString string] subviews]`, you should *appreciate* a runtime (and/or compiler) error/warning, rather than the implementation attempting to mask that error :) fail hard. fail early.